# C# - complicated regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

So I have quite a big problem...

I get a string like:

```
'x,y',2,4,'y,z'
```

And I need to seperate it into

- 'x,y'
- 2
- 4
- 'y,z'

Nothing I tried came anywhere near the expected result...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I recommend getting a CSV parser, while this sort of thing can be done in regular expressions, it's not worth it.

Comment: @juharr Can a CSV parser do that?

Comment: @Riad I already wrote that nothing I tried worked... There's no need for my code...

Comment: Yes, you might have to configure it to use single quotes but this is exactly what a CSV parser is for.

Comment: @Azeros, Your comment to Riad looks very rude, remember that the people here are spending time to solve YOUR issues and they are doing it for free.

Comment: @Thangadurai How did it look rude? I just stated that I, personaly, don't See the need for my code. If it really WAS rude I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a *quick solution*, try this (simple *loop* and no *regular expressions*):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> CsvSplitter(string source) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    yield break; //TODO: you may want to throw exception in case source == null

  int lastIndex = 0;
  bool inQuot = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i) {
    char c = source[i];

    if (inQuot) 
      inQuot = c != '\'';
    else if (c == '\'')
      inQuot = true;
    else if (c == ',') {
      yield return source.Substring(lastIndex, i - lastIndex);

      lastIndex = i + 1;
    }
  }

  //TODO: you can well have invalid csv (unterminated quotation):
  // if (inQuot)
  //   throw new FormatException("Incorrect CSV");

  yield return source.Substring(lastIndex);
}
```

Sample:

```
string source = @"'x,y',2,4,'y,z',";
string[] result = CsvSplitter(source).ToArray();

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
'x,y'
2
4
'y,z'
```

However, in *general case* google for *CSV parser*

Comment: Thank you very much!
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna go the regex way, you can use

```
('.*?'|[^,]+)
```

and browse the capture groups, but I **strongly** recommend you to use a CSV parser.

Comment: A difficulty can appear if we want to include quotation symbol (`'` in the case) into data; in CSV we usually *double* the quotation symbol, e.g.:
`"'x,''y',2,4,'y,z'"` should be parsed as `['x,''y', 2, 4, 'y,z']`. That's why *regular expression* seems to be a partial solution and I totally agree with your strong recomendation.

Answer (score 1):

If no nested quotes allowed, we can retrieve the required parts with a simple regex [`'.*?'|[^,]+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27.*%3f%27%7c%5b%5e%2c%5d%2b&i=%27x%2cy%27%2c2%2c4%2c%27y%2cz%27):

```
var input = "'x,y',2,4,'y,z'";

var parts = Regex
  .Matches(input, "'.*?'|[^,]+")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Value)
  .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, parts));
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qo5aHz

Although .NET flavour allows to elaborate a regex for nested quotes, it would be rather hard and therefore it's best to use a ready-made CSV parser. For example, [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) provided with .NET.

Comment: A bit weird *counter example*: in CSV we *double* quotation symbol if we want to include it: `"'x,''y',2,4,'y,z'"` should be parsed as `['x,''y', 2, 4, 'y,z']`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: yes, you're right, my code would fail on such input. That's why I explicitly restricted the cases where this is applicable. I just wanted to share a simple on-line solution for the cases where no quotes inside quotes expected.